# Spring BeanDefinitionStoreException when extending abstract class

Tags: java, spring, maven, guava

I created a class that extends the abstract class [AbstractScheduledService](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.html).

```
@Service
public class MyClass extends AbstractScheduledService {

    public MyClass(){
        super();
        ...
    }
}
```

I added required dependency to my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When Running my app getting the below exception,
Don't really know why. I can see the AbstractScheduledService.class file under the relevant jar of the maven dependencies of this project.

How can I fix it?

```
11 Aug 2014 10:17:33 ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: com.company.app.MyClass; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:162)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:299)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:775)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:767)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:82)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:77)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:563)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:726)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:287)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:158)
        ... 41 more
```

Comment: Are you sure you add guava jar right place?

Comment: You mean the right place in the pom? Yes, it is under the <dependencies> element

Comment: But it is a FileNotFoundException. You should check AbstractScheduledService class in your classpath.

Comment: I agree and this is a maven dependency which means all maven dependencies should be under the classpath by default (this is the maven project structure convention).

Comment: It's more than likely that you have another version of Guava already resolved as dependency in your dependency tree. Check it and force your version of Guava. `AbstractScheduledService` appeared in Guava 11.0. My guess is that the indirect dependency you're looking for is older than that.

Comment: I agree with Olivier. I know how to maven works. It probably add guava jar but you should check the class in right version.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You are right, I do see 2 different jars of guava, one of version 9 and other in different project version 17. How do I force the usage of a specific version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the question comments, in the dependency that has a link to guava 9.0, type the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some_group</groupId>
  <artifactId>some_artifact</artifactId>
  <version>some_version</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This will force the library using guava to use your version instead (in this case, 17.0). Careful though because Guava often deprecates its functions for various reasons, most notably, they rename a lot. So you might end up with errors in the code of the library using guava because that library cannot find the appropriate class or method.